# Changing button text from modal view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have to buttons. Each one open the same view controller modally. In there, I have a TableView which needs to return the value selected and set the button the opened it to that value.

Everything works, except the buttons text does not change.

I have tried setting the modal views delegate - no option to do so, from the original view controller or the modal one.

Tried calling presentingViewController - always nil for some reason. Cannot get it to say otherwise.

Tried having a method which sets the button text - get the "Optional.none" error as the button has not been initialized yet.

tried setting a variable and having the viewDidAppear method change the text - variable remains unchanged when the view comes back into view.

Code presenting the modal view:

```
@IBAction func getFromStation(sender : AnyObject) {
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : informationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("informationViewController") as informationViewController
    vc.parent = "RoutePlannerFrom"
    self.presentModalViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Code trying to return the value selected:

```
let vc : RoutePlannerViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("routePlannerViewController") as RoutePlannerViewController
        vc.btnFrom.setTitle(stopNames[indexPath.row] as String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Any pointers? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a good problem for the [delegation pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)

In the `InformationViewController` you can define a new delegate protocol:

```
protocol InformationDelegate {
    func didSelectValue(value: String)
}

class InformationViewController {
   var delegate: InformationDelegate?  // The delegate that the parent view controller will conform to
   ...

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
      // Get the value and call the delegate method
      if let d = self.delegate {
         d.didSelectValue(valueForButton) // Get the value from your datasource and return it to the parent through the delegate method.
      }
   }
}
```

In the parent view controller you will want to conform to this delegate protocol:

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController, InformationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var btnFrom: UIButton
    ....

    func didSelectValue(value: String) {
        self.btnFrom.setTitle(value)
    }


    @IBAction func getFromStation(sender : AnyObject) {
       let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let vc : informationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("informationViewController") as informationViewController
       vc.parent = "RoutePlannerFrom"
       vc.delegate = self // Set up this class as the InformationsViewControllers delegate
       self.presentModalViewController(vc, animated: true)
     }

}
```

Hopefully this gives you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But how to pass multiple values?